# Nagios: NRPE: Unable to read output

Tags: linux, nagios, centos7

I have installed Nagios and NRPE plugins on the same server (CentOs 7).

The preinstalled services like check_disk work fine, but my manually intalled plugins always end up with following error:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_cpu -a 20 10
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             CPU
    check_command                   check_cpu!20!10
    notifications_enabled           0
    }
```

/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg

```
define command {
    command_name    check_cpu
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_cpu -t 30 -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
}
```

/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg

```
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20 -c 10
command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 30 -c 200
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpu_perf.sh -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_procs_cron]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -a cron
command[check_mem]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem_ng.sh -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

Output messages.log

```
Nov 29 19:52:03 localhost xinetd[25346]: START: nrpe pid=25575 from=::ffff:127.0.0.1
Nov 29 19:52:03 localhost nrpe[25575]: INFO: SSL/TLS initialized. All network traffic will be encrypted.
Nov 29 19:52:03 localhost xinetd[25346]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=25575 duration=0(sec)
```

**additional information:**

Output of `/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe`:

```
# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
    flags           = REUSE
    socket_type     = stream
    port            = 5666
    wait            = no
    user            = nagios
    group           = nagios
    server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
    server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
    log_on_failure  += USERID
    disable         = no
    only_from       = 127.0.0.1
}
```

Output from `netstat -at | grep nrpe`:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:51424         localhost:nrpe          TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 [::]:nrpe               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Does anyone have a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the command configuration file `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg` 
instead of **$USER1$** try with absolute path - ***/usr/local/nagios/libexec/***

Restart Nagios service and check.

One more thing I found in your question is you said "check_disk work fine, but my manually intalled plugins always end up with error" and in your **/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg** file there is a configuration of **check_disk** command `command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20 -c 10` but there is no configuration of **check_cpu** command. So when you try to execute this `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_cpu -a 20 10` it actually consults your **nrpe.cfg** file and found **no check_cpu command configuration**. 
Just add configuration for **check_cpu in nrpe.cfg file** and it should work then.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but didnt help. Like I mentioned, the following doesnt work:
`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_mem`
The default check_disk works, just my additional plugins check_cpu_perf.sh and/or check_mem_ng.sh don't work. Do those shell scripts need special treatment?

Comment: Can you update your question with `/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe` file configuration and `netstat -at | grep nrpe` output

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. I'm not sure if I understand your updated answer: I did specify the check_cpu command in my /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg file (like you can see in my original post 
`command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpu_perf.sh -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$?`
Or do you mean something different?
Maybe it's a permission problem? Or do you know if there is any other log where I could find more detailed information of whats going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Check this link https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/NRPE-Troubleshooting-and-Common-Solutions.pdf. 
You can find some help on page 8 from above doc. It says about sudo privileges.